# webpack load js file,some success but others : Unexpected token export

Tags: webpack, babeljs

[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY4Pm.png)

```
// webpack config  
var path = require('path');  
var projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname , '../');  

module.exports = {  
    resolve: {  
        alias: {  
            'components': path.resolve(projectRoot, 'components')  
        }  
    },  
    module: {  
        loaders:[  
            {  
                test: /\.vue$/,  
                loader: 'vue'  
            },  
            {  
                test: /\.js$/,  
                loader: 'babel',  
                include: projectRoot,  
                exclude: /node_modules/  
            },  
        ]  
    }  
};  

// .babelrc

{  
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"],  
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],  
  "comments": false  
}  

// components/button/index.js

import Button from './src/Button.vue';  

Button.install = function(Vue) {  
    Vue.component(Button.name, Button);  
};  

export default Button;  

// src/utils/validator.js

export function isOneOf (value, validList) {  
  for (let i = 0; i < validList.length; i++) {  
    if (value === validList[i]) {  
      return true  
    }  
  }  
  return false  
}
```

when i use karma to do unit test , it print :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8lGS.png)

but components/button/index.js use import/export too, why just src/utils/validator.js print error?

and if i don't use the validator.js,it test success without error.

if i miss something?

Comment: what does your test file look like?

Comment: @darryn.ten  i write a simple test like:

Comment: import Button from 'components/button'

describe('button', () => {
        it('test', () => {
            expect('ok').to.equal('ok')
        })
    }
)